# RXTX issue with Bluetooth COM Port

Tags: java, bluetooth, serial-port, rxtx

I have an application made of a device I made to connect through USB emulating a Serial port. Now, I need to connect the same device via bluetooth so I'm using a RN-42 (Bluetooth to serial port) in my device to send the data over RF.

Then I pair my device in Windows with the laptop's internal BT module which creates to COM ports a Outgoing and a Incoming one. Then if I connect using Br@ay's terminal I receive the expected data when I connect to the Outgoing COM port.

The problem is that when I use my Java app where I am using the last RXTX libraries, I can discover the COM port (which is the problem that everyone has, at least thats all what i found in forums) and it seems to connect but then I don't receive no data. Using the same exact program but connecting using a cable it works just fine as the terminal does.

I also tried to use the BlueCove libraries, I can find the bluetooth devices but I don't really know how to discover it services and then connect to it using RFComm. I can't find a complete example of how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting similar problem with default Windows Bluetooth stack.
With Toshiba stack communication is ok.